# Swift NSMutableURLRequest URLSession callback not being called

Tags: swift

I'm having some trouble getting a very simple Swift HTTP POST to work.

I currently have simple command line project, and main.swift consists of

```
import Foundation

let url = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1/input.php")!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let paramString = "value=100&dataPointId=1"
request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:  {

    (let data, let response, let error) in

    print("callback")

    guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
}

    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(dataString)

}).resume()
```

I verified that my PHP script works using Postman, but when I run this code, I get nothing. I am watching the Apache access logs and it doesn't even attempt the HTTP request.

It's like the callback function isn't being called. I would expect at least to see the output of print("callback"), but nothing happens.

Is my program exiting too soon and not allowing the callback to happen? Or is something else going on?

This isn't being executed in a Playground, and is using the built-in URL handling libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay in making http requests using Alamofire in playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535968/delay-in-making-http-requests-using-alamofire-in-playground)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the program exited before the callback could occur. Added a simple `sleep(5)` at the end of the program which gave it time to finish. This won't be required in a regular Cocoa GUI application, since the program won't exit immediately like this.